# Multiple sql queries to single query using inner join

Tags: java, sql, join

i have this java code:

```
ArrayList<MessageMap> ids = getNewMail(UserID, type, maxIdMessage);
Message[] message = new Message[ids.size()];
if(ids.size()>0){
   ResultSet rs;
   int j =0;
   for(MappaMessaggi i : ids){
      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Messaggi WHERE MessageID = ?");
      pstmt.setInt(1, i.getMessageID());
      rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
      rs.next();
      .
      .
      .
   }
```

where `getNewMail` is:

```
public synchronized ArrayList<MessageMap> getNewMail(int UserID,int type,int max){
   ArrayList<MessageMap> map = new ArrayList<MessageMap>();
   try {
      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MessageMap WHERE UserID = ? AND TipoID = ? AND MessageID > ?");
      .
      .//fill arraylist with resultSet 
      .
}
```

I know that is possible to do the same with just one query but i don't know how.. can someone open my eyes? :) thanks!!!

EDIT:  i try:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM Messaggi AS i
INNER JOIN MessageMap AS p i.MessageID = p.MessageID
WHERE p.MessageID = 1 AND p.UserID = 1 AND p.TipoID = 2
```

BUT I RETRIEVE:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'i.MessageID = p.MessageID WHERE p.MessageID = 1 AND p.UserID = 1 AND p.TipoID = ' at line 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT i.*, p.*
FROM Messaggi i
INNER JOIN MessageMap p ON i.MessageID = p.MessageID
WHERE i.MessageID = ? AND p.UserID = ? AND p.TipoID = ?
```

Comment: @JackTurky, Sorry I forgot the `ON`, see my edit. It should be `INNER JOIN MessageMap p ON i.MessageID = p.MessageID` instead of `INNER JOIN MessageMap p i.MessageID = p.MessageID`.

Answer (score 1):

Based in your question and queries, the simple solution I find could be this query (maybe there are another columns that relate your tables)

```
SELECT A.*
FROM MessageMap A
    INNER JOIN Message B on A.MessageId = B.MessageId
WHERE
    A.UserId = ?
    AND A.TipoID = ?
    AND A.MessageId = ?
```

Also, please specify if you need those 3 parameters or you could not send any of them.

Comment: Probably just `Messaggi.*` to be honest.